# Scrape a webpage that requires acess from another url using Python

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a webpage that requires me to go through one URL/ link to access the site (sort of like a login link) but then I need to loop another URL through that link to scrape individual pages. I know how to scrape individual pages I just have never had to loop URL's to another URL to gain access to a site.

Am I on the right path with this idea or am I missing something here?

Sorry if this is a bit confusing.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import pyfpdf
import time
import random
timeDelay = random.randrange(5, 10)

my_url = 'http://shops3.directedje.com/JACK/product-listing.asp?CID=2065'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print ("href")
```

This is the link that I need to access first thermofisher.com/DCG

Comment: Please show us the code you already have!

Comment: @KlausD. I have updated the post

Comment: Can't you first visit the login page, send the account credentials and then go on the needed page?

Comment: Is it a login page, or does thermofisher.com/DCG just need to be in the header as Referer?

Comment: @AfloroaieRobert no for some reason the people who set up this page do not allow people to have credentials and only allow them to use the links given to access the site. Otherwise I would have just set it up to login.

Comment: @RandomHash the link automatically gives to access to the webpage using my computers credentials but as I said before they don't have credentials that you can manually input in the login page. I know this sounds ridiculous but this is what I have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You need to use Requests-NTLM. This will allow for windows Authentication over HTTP.

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth



requests.get("http://ntlm_protected_site.com",auth=HttpNtlmAuth('domain\\username','password'))
```

Then you need to follow the redirect 302 response code. Which should be the url you want.

Comment: @user9269112 You say authentication does actually occur? Through your windows credentials, or cookies? Can you explain this further?

Comment: @user9269112 it occurs thru my windows credentials on my computer.